# Wordpress import doesnt accept some images

Tags: php, wordpress

I am moving my wordpress from live to local, to make some changes and then upload it again on a new host. When I finished uploading the XML, some images were missing, and now I am unable to upload THAT images. I can upload any other one, but for some reasons, even if i resize in photoshop, change the filename or any other thing, I cannot upload that specific ones. 
The only time the image shows up in Wordpress is when i try to edit it.
Does somebody have any idea? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a FTP client to check the permissions of those image files. Sounds like they are lacking read/execute permissions.  Typically permissions will be
755   full control for the owner(you) and read/execute permissions for everyone else

Comment: It's installed in localhost - i have tried to go in htdocs and then right click on the folder -> properties -> security -> and allow full control. I unticked the read only property. I went inside the folder and i deleted the htaccess. Nothing works

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just can't imagine using anything other than a linux based webserver. Is it possible some of the images were downloaded from the old server as ASCII instead of as binary files?

Comment: I dont know, how can i check this? I just noticed that Photoshop doesnt allow me to save the (PNG) image as .jpg; I think maybe what you suggested could be the problem!! Thank you Duane!

Comment: I tried tking a screenshot, cropping it and uploading it and still doesnt work. I dont know how my wordpress can recognize that images

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, if it can be useful to somebody. The site I was editing was in brasilian portuguese, and some pictures had special characters in their filenames like ç or ã.
I went through all the wp-content -> uploads and substituted these characters and solved